# Restricting Backward movement in Business Process Flow (CRM 2015)

Tags: crm, dynamics-crm-2013, dynamics-crm-2015

We have a certain requirement in CRM 2015 in which we need to restrict backward movement in Business Process Flow for Non-S/S Admin users.

I iterated through Client API’s (including scripting for Upgrade 1) but I didn’t find any API for achieving using any of the exposed method. So, finally I wrote custom code for this by hijacking the backward movement of the Business Process Flow and prompting user that this is the restricted move for Non-S/S admin users.

However, this is an unsupported change and I see this won’t be an issue as long as DOM ids are same (since on a quick look I found DOM Ids are same in 2013, 2015 and 2015 Rollup1 for BPF).

```
function restrictBPFPreviousMove() {
    var originalPreviousStageHandler = $("#stageBackActionContainer").data("events")["click"][0].handler;

    $("#stageBackActionContainer").unbind("click");
    $("#stageBackActionContainer").click(function (e) {
        alert("Restricted Back Move!");
    });
}
```

However, I was wondering if there is any alternative (supported) to this approach?

Answer (score 4):

[CRM 2015 has events for stage selection and change that can be handled.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f451f339-bcee-4260-9904-abc8c0efa153#BKMK_BPFControl)

> Business Process Flow control events
>
> Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2015 and
>   Microsoft Dynamics CRM Online 2015 Update provides two events for user
>   interaction with the business process flow control. OnStageChange
>   Occurs when a stage changes. More information: OnStageChange event.
>   OnStageSelected Occurs when a stage is selected. More information:
>   OnStageSelected event. There is no UI to register scripts for these
>   events. Use the following methods in functions registered in the form
>   OnLoad event to register your functions for these events.
>
> Xrm.Page.data.process.addOnStageChange
>
> Xrm.Page.data.process.addOnStageSelected
>
> Xrm.Page.data.process.removeOnStageChange
>
> Xrm.Page.data.process.removeOnStageSelected

You still have to check the role of the user by hand (retrieve `systemuser`, retrieve `role`, mix & match)

Answer (score 0):

First get all the Stages `guid` with `Xrm.Page.data.process.getActiveProcess().getStages()` and store it in `var` as

```js
var stage1= "efe2a761-9f5c-492c-9843-54decc2ab76a";
var stage2= "dddddd34-9f5c-492c-9843-54decc2ab76a";
var stage3= "abcdef12-9f5c-492c-9843-54decc2ab76a";
```

Next add a `Event Handler` using `Xrm.Page.data.process.addOnStageChange()` that checks for the Active stage `guid` as

```js
var currentStageId = Xrm.Page.data.process.getActiveStage().getId();
```

then you try moving the stage using either of the following

```js
Xrm.Page.data.process.moveNext();
Xrm.Page.data.process.movePrevious();
Xrm.Page.data.process.setActiveStage();
```